# Why am i getting "java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found"?

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
        try{
            String url = params[0].replace("\\", "");
            Log.v("before", params[0]);
            Log.v("after", url);
            InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
            return d;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Image Error", e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

> 7-07 22:02:03.282: before(21811):
>   "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/inradar.media/uploads/ads/ad-60cd15be59b21725e45c5cf388065527.jpg"
>
> 07-07 22:02:03.282: after(21811):
>   "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/inradar.media/uploads/ads/ad-60cd15be59b21725e45c5cf388065527.jpg"
>
> 07-07 22:02:03.282: Image Error(21811):
>   java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found:
>   "https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/inradar.media/uploads/ads/ad-60cd15be59b21725e45c5cf388065527.jpg"

Comment: Are the quotes part of the string or part of the log?

Comment: I'm not sure of that. I tried your url with quotes and I got the same exception.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis If you hardcode it, it works. It might be something with the string escaping maybe.

Comment: @PatrickBassut Which string escaping?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm not a java expert. But for some reason when the URL contructor is called it might leaving those "\/", "//" unescaped(that would explain the except. The reason being a "http\/\/:" at the begin of the string). Because if you get the url thats printed on the console, and call the URL constructor with it, it works. Get it?

Comment: @Patrick Right. So _escaping_ characters in Strings is only important for `String` _literals_, that is string values hardcoded in the source code. Escape characters are removed (converted to a value) at runtime. The value in the logs is a `String` in memory. It appears to contain leading and ending quotation marks `"`. This will cause the URL parser to fail.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis would that happen if the source was a json array of simple-quoted strings?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Cause if so, java would not remove the simple quotes. Right?

Comment: @Patrick The `String` literal (ie. in source code) `String url = "\"http:\"";` has the `String` value `"http:"` at runtime. If your question refers to something like a JSON array `["value1", "value2"]`, the answer depends on the parser. A proper parser will determine that the elements are JSON Strings and produce two `String` objects in an array with the values `value1` and `value2`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think you should make it an answer so the OP can accepts it. Or not. But it's definitely an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any logger that will add enclosing quotes to a given log message. As such, I'm going to assume that your `url` `String` is literally

```
"https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/inradar.media/uploads/ads/ad-60cd15be59b21725e45c5cf388065527.jpg"
```

The `URL` constructor cannot parse that value. Get rid of the leading and trailing quotation marks.